# Using rollup with a view gives me an empty field?

Tags: mysql, view, subquery, rollup

I've been smashing my head against this for a few days, so I decided to create a sample data set to prove to myself it wasn't our monolithic schema that's breaking things. But nope, it still happens.

```
CREATE TABLE test_data (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `label` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE VIEW test_view AS
SELECT id, label 
FROM test_data;


INSERT INTO test_data VALUES
(1, 'red'),
(2, 'red'),
(3, 'red'),
(4, 'red'),
(5, 'green'),
(6, 'green'),
(7, 'green'),
(8, 'yellow'),
(9, 'yellow'),
(10, 'yellow'),
(11, 'blue'),
(12, 'blue'),
(13, 'blue'),
(14, 'blue'),
(15, 'blue'),
(16, 'blue');
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vMwvXDtReEwfAtGjYw4xEt/0

So we have a table with some data, and then we select it using group by with rollup:

```
SELECT label, COUNT(id) as cnt FROM test_data GROUP BY label WITH ROLLUP
```

Then there's another query wrapped around this (which in the real world does other things, in this example is just pulling data from the select).

```
SELECT COALESCE(label, 'TOTAL') as wrap_label, label, cnt FROM
(
    SELECT label, COUNT(id) as cnt FROM test_data GROUP BY label WITH ROLLUP
) as d;
```

When I pull directly from a table, it works perfectly, we get the final line with TOTAL as the wrap_label. However if there's a view (which is essentially a SELECT * from test_data) involved it stops pulling out the wrap_label:

```
SELECT COALESCE(label, 'TOTAL') as wrap_label, label, cnt FROM
(
    SELECT label, COUNT(id) as cnt FROM test_view GROUP BY label WITH ROLLUP
) as d;
```

If you run the fiddle above you'll see that Query #2 has TOTAL, Query #4 has a blank identifier. weirdly the subqueries (#1 from the table, #3 from the view) both seem to return the exact same data!

Is this expected behaviour? I'm guessing it's something to do with execution order and the select or the group by from the view is happening AFTER the subquery is trying to pull?

Obviously this is easily fixed by ditching the subselect and just doing

```
SELECT COALESCE(label, 'TOTAL') as label, COUNT(id) as cnt FROM test_view GROUP BY label WITH ROLLUP;
```

but this is the real world and I can't do that I'm afraid, the outer query does more and is in many places in our massive codebase.

I'd appreciate any insight anyone might have.

Cheers,
Si.

Comment: You could just do the ROLLUP stuff in your application code.

Comment: Could be that dbfiddle is wrong query #4 works fine for me on my server..I suggest you test this locally.

Comment: @P.Salmon that's interesting because the results of the fiddle pretty much mirror what we get on our server. We get a zero on ours for some reason rather than a blank field.

Comment: @Strawberry if I was starting from scratch I'd definitely agree, path of least resistance and all that. Unfortunately we have two huge codebases sharing the same db, one with views, and making changes right across the board is just untenable from a resource point of view. So I'm really hoping someone can just show me a mysql side work around :)